# C++ && multithreads: если нужна блокировка на отдельные узлы std::map, это нужны мютексы в каждом узле, или есть более оптимальный вариант?

Tags: c++, mutex

Если в многопоточной проге нужна блокировка отдельных узлов на std::map, то это нужно мютексы делать в каждом узле, или есть более оптимальные варианты?

Видел, что sizeof(std::mutex) занимает 40 байт, а sizeof(std::shared_mutex) вообще 56 байт. В моем случае это несколько избыточно. У меня деревья нужны на миллионы и более узлов.

В то же время, делать общую блокировку всего дерева то же избыточно. Обращения к дереву часты, но использование одного и того же узла очень редки.

Структура в среднем вот такого плана:

```
struct CounterItem {
   mutable std::shared_mutex mtx;
   mutable SomeComplexCounter counter;
};

...

std::map<Key,CounterItem> mapCounters;

...

auto& item = mapCounters.at(someKey);
item.mtx.lock();
item.counter.doSomeThing();
item.mtx.unlock();
```

Вопроса про общую блокировку дерева нет, с ней все понятно.

Comment: заведите отдельный std::map для мьютексов и добавляйте-удаляйте их от туда при необходимости

Comment: В этом случае этот отдельный std::map будет по размерности близким к первому, т.к. на каждый элемент первого нужен отдельный мютекс. Либо добавлять в этот второй мап в момент набодности, и удалять по завершению операции, что то же бессмыслица, т.к. нужен еще и общий мютекс.

Comment: Сейчас вот мысль возникла, что можно в узле сделать указатель на мютекс, изначально инициализированным нулом. Тогда общий мютекс потребуется включать только при создании мютекса в элементе. А эти мютексы в элементах периодически чистить все по достижении некого критического количества их. Но как-то все равно это стремно.

Comment: Почитайте про lock-free.

Comment: Возьмите готовую библиотеку. [Вот тут](https://github.com/greg7mdp/parallel-hashmap) есть потоко-безопасные хешмапы (а может и не хеш- тоже).

Comment: если у вас обращения в основном на чтение, то может быть есть смысл сделать MRSW блокировку всего дерева (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: вот ещё библиотека, может подойдёт https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Containers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подумал я, поизучал вопрос, и сделал собственный мютекс основанный на std::atomic.

Вот так вот выглядит сам класс. Тип вложенной переменной можно объявить хоть char - и тогда sizeof будет 1 байт, если таковой размер char. По крайней мере смотрел на gcc под линуксом.

```
template <class TT>
struct AtomicMutex {
    static_assert( TT(-1) < 0, "Need signed numeric type");

    void lockForWrite();
    void unlockForWrite();
    void lockForRead();
    void unlockForRead();

private:
    std::atomic<TT> counter = 0;
};
```

Вот так вот выглядит реализация:

```
template <class TT>
void AtomicMutex<TT>::lockForWrite() {
    TT v = 0;
    while (!counter.compare_exchange_weak(v, -1)) {
        counter.wait(v);
        v = 0;
    }
}

template <class TT>
void AtomicMutex<TT>::unlockForWrite() {
    counter = 0;
    counter.notify_all();
}

template <class TT>
void AtomicMutex<TT>::lockForRead() {
    while (true) {
        TT v = counter.load();
        if (v < 0)
            counter.wait(v);
        else if (counter.compare_exchange_weak(v, v+1))
            break;
    }
}

template <class TT>
void AtomicMutex<TT>::unlockForRead() {
    while (true) {
        TT v = counter.load();
        assert( v > 0 );
        if (counter.compare_exchange_weak(v, v-1)) {
            if (v == 1)
                counter.notify_all();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

По прямому назначению - инстанцировать в итемы еще не пробовал. Но в паре своих прежних расчетных алгоритмов заменил QReadWriteLock на этот класс. Там в 15 потоков активного использования заработало без сбоев. Компилировал на gcc под линукс, на Intel процессоре.

Вот здесь можно посмотреть на гитхабе: https://github.com/victorprogrammist/atomic_mutex

Будут интересны замечания про надежность этого метода. Мютекс планируется использовать в итемах коллекций, где пересечения блокировок редки, поэтому скорость работы относительно стандартных мютексов не сильно беспокоит.